# adding custom css/js files in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

in laravel, which one is the proper way to add custom css & js files:

- in public folder
- in resource folder

I added my custom css/js files in resource folder but not working. But it works when I added my css and js files in public folder. Need a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

1. Drag/drop them in the `/public` directory
2. Place the file in the `/resources` directory, and in your build tool, copy the file(s)/directory(ies) from `/resources` to `/public`

If you use #1, be sure to add/include it the file(s) in your VCS.

Laravel has documentation on #2: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#copying-files-and-directories

Comment: that means if I want to add a custom css file like **style.css** in my laravel project then it is better to put that css file in both public and resource directory. i.e,

`public/css/style.css, 
resources/assets/css/style.css`

Comment: There's no need to add it to both, one or the other would work. I have always used #2, so placed the custom css file in my `resources/css` folder and then `@import ../css/<file>.css in my SASS (or, converted it to a SASS file). Or, you could place the file in `resources/css`, and then just copy it to `/public/css` and then link to it as normal (`/css/<file>.css`) in your HTML